# Does anyone know which gallery script is used here?

Tags: scripting

I came across this [website](http://www.outinsaigon.com/galleries/09.07.10.5,000/) and really liked their gallery, not sure if the script is in-house or came from some free/commercial script out there ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's Flash based. There are plenty of javascript galleries that can do some really cool stuff. Below has a list of many

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/

Answer (score 2):

Its AutoViewer:

http://www.simpleviewer.net/products/